# How to write shell script for chaincode invoke function for arguments from file?

Tags: bash, shell, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I want to invoke chaincode to write data for 10 records automatically with using bash script and arguments for chaincode can be able to take from txt file.But, chaincode does not write to ledger from file, it writes only value "line1" and "line2".

```
#!/bin/bash while read -r line1 <&3 && read -r line2 <&4; do
peer chaincode invoke -c '{"Args":["createDocRecord", "$line1" , "$line2"]}' -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C bloom-filter-channel -n bloom-filter --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051  done 3<scripts/10.txt 4<scripts/data10.txt`
```

Why it does not take string values from txt file?

Comment: does it work when you remove the chaincode component and just do something simple like `printf "#dbg : line1="|$line1| and line2=|$line2|\n"`? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter yes it works when I use just echo command

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a timeout.
You are probably running the invoke while the first transaction is not validated and committed yet, I don't know how you configured your network.

So do someting like:

```
peer chaincode invoke -c '{"Args":["createDocRecord", "$line1" , "$line2"]}' -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C bloom-filter-channel -n bloom-filter --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051  done 3<scripts/10.txt 4<scripts/data10.txt`

timeout 5

repeat
```

Comment: I am sorry but it didn't help.